# protobuf error: This file was generated by an older version of protoc

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, protocol-buffers

I'm attempting to develop a program to demonstrate the use of protobuf.

Package Manager : vcpkg
C++ Standard : C++20
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

Install Log

```
vcpkg.exe install protobuf
Computing installation plan...
The following packages are already installed:
    protobuf[core]:x64-windows -> 3.21.4
protobuf:x64-windows is already installed
Restored 0 package(s) from C:\Users\DarkSorrow\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 409.1 us. Use --debug to see more details.

Total elapsed time: 130.8 ms

protobuf provides CMake targets:

    # this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
    find_package(protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE protobuf::libprotoc protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
```

I am getting the bellow mentioned error.

Error :

```
fatal  error C1189: #error:  This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
```

I have not written any code but only included the generated file in the project.

Code Generation :

```
 protoc test.proto --cpp_out=.
```

Code (test.proto) :

```
syntax = "proto3";
message Person {
  optional string name = 1;
  optional int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

Protocol Buffer Generator Version

```
protoc --version
libprotoc 3.16.0
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me. You are running `protoc` built against v3.16.0 of protobuf runtime, but are trying to use the files it produced with 3.21.4 runtime. You need a copy of `protoc` that matches the runtime you want to build with. My guess would be, you have multiple copies installed, of different versions, and are running the wrong copy.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have used `vcpkg` Package Manager.
I shall delete and purge the package along with its tools and retry.

Answer (score 0):

You must execute:
Protoc.exe command:

```
protoc --proto_path=[full path where exist file[ProtobufTypes.proto] --cpp_out=[full path where exist file[ProtobufTypes.proto] [full path where exist file[ProtobufTypes.proto]/ProtobufTypes.proto
```